# Tablayout with Viewpager programatically creating is not working

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

**Activity Class :**

```
public class DynamicActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private View mView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(DynamicActivity.this);
        mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


        TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(DynamicActivity.this);
        tabLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        mLinearLayout.addView(tabLayout);


        ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(DynamicActivity.this);
        viewPager.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        viewPager.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        mLinearLayout.addView(viewPager);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        setContentView(mLinearLayout);
    }
}

**Adapter Class :**
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Test";
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new TestFagment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

**Exception :**

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                           Process: com.example.locale.tablayoutdynamicsample, PID: 27084
                                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager with adapter com.example.locale.tablayoutdynamicsample.ViewPagerAdapter@3b0e90d6 requires a view id
                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.startUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:87)
                                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1148)
                                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2897)
                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says "`VewPager with Adapter ViewPagerAdapter@3b0e90d6 requires a view id`" so try this:

```
viewPager.setId(anyInteger);
```

Comment: >>sorry i didn't find this in method in viewPagerAdapter class                            viewPagerAdapter.setId(anyInteger);                                                                   Can you please tell me to which class do i need to set ID.                                                         When i inflate Tablyout withViewpager from xml adapter works fine but when i do dynamically it is  throwing exception.

Comment: Yeah.Thank you."setId(0)"added as per your suggestion.But i was able to set only viewPager.setId(0) but not any integer only '0' i was able to set and Viewpager content is not displayed,on debugging respective fragment i.e TestFragment was getting called.And viewpager swiping/scrolling is not smooth.Please let me know if i have missed anything.

Comment: No worries. You'll need to post a new question for that. If my answer solved the crash, could you mark is as accepted please? :)

Comment: done. can you please check why fragment content is not displayed.